# Форма в форме php

Tags: php, html, post, form, get

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть альтернативы форма в форме php.
Есть форма, которая тянется через всю страницу, как в этой форме сделать еще одну форму с post или get запросом?

Comment: Форма в форме - это плохое решение.

Comment: @u_mulder я понимаю, и из-за этого ищу альтернативы.

Comment: В html5 у инпутов есть аттрибут `form`, который должен содержать id формы, к которой они относятся. То есть, вы можете закрыть первую форму, начать и закончить вторую, а потом просто без тега `form` вставить еще инпуты с аттрибутом `form`.

Comment: @u_mulder у меня вместо input стоит данный код <a onclick='this.parentNode.submit(); return false;' class='con-vis' form='delete'><span class='fas fa-trash-alt'></span></a> как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @u_mulder и когда закрываю первую часть первой формы, вторая часть первой формы не отправляется.

Comment: @u_mulder по хорошему мне форма как бы и не нужна, я могу отправить все переменные через ссылку и потом на стороне забрать эти переменные через php, но есть одна проблема, эта ссылка не должна быть видна в коде, так же как и форма.

Comment: ссылку всегда в исходной странице можно найти, как ни крути :)

Comment: @Alexxosipov я не спорю, по хорошему и форму отследить проблем не составляет, но суть в том что бы ссылка хотя бы в коде сильно не светилась https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908149/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-ajax