# Как спрятать ссылку ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно спрятать ссылку в коде что бы она была не видна.
Пробовал так, но выполняе

```js
$(function(){
    $('#link42').click(function(){
        window.open("http://site.ru/");
    });
});
```

```css
.link {
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #00f;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p>Вообще, это не самый лучший вариант, но если хочется, то кликни по <span id='link42' class='link'>псевдо-ссылке</span>.</p>
<p>Вообще, это не самый лучший вариант, но если хочется, то кликни по <span id='link42' class='link'>псевдо-ссылке</span>.</p>
```

Comment: всмысле в коде?

Comment: @Санитариум это оставим, подскажите почему удается перейти только по первой ссылке?

Comment: id  должен быть уникальным а у вас он одниковый у 2 элементов.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a style='font-size: 14px;color: #777777;' id='kurl' href='javascript: goToPage(".$id.");'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a>
        <script type= 'text/javascript'>
    function goToPage(tx)
    {
        var tx = '".$id."';
    var url = document.getElementById('kurl');
    document.location.href = '/fun/awg.php/?id=".$id."&id_t=".$_GET['id']."';
}
</script>
```